# Can't get my form data to submit into my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, apache

I can't get my ban system to work for my website and I tried for a few hours to see what the issue was. I tried everything. Even looked up on youTube. Think you guys can help? Here is the submit code for the database. Also, i dont want to hear that i'm using "Bad PHP and should use Mysqli" I will change it until the next major php update.

```
if (isset($_POST['post']))
{

 //get data
 $bannuser = $_POST['bannuser'];

 $TypeBan = $_POST['TypeBan'];
 $Reviewed = $_POST['Reviewed'];
 $ModNote = $_POST['ModNote'];
 $Reason = $_POST['Reason'];
 $OffenItem = $_POST['OffenItem'];
 $BanLengthMssg = $_POST['BanLengthMssg'];
 $ReleaseMssg = $_POST['ReleaseMssg'];
 $AppealMssg = $_POST['AppealMssg'];



 //Connect To The Database
 $connect = mysql_connect("####","####","####");
 mysql_select_db("####");

 $namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT bannuser FROM banned WHERE bannuser='$bannuser'");
 $count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);

 if($count!=0)
 {
    die("This User Is Already Banned! <a href='home.php'>[Home]</a>");
 }

 //check for existance
 if ($bannuser)
 {
    if(strlen($bannuser)>25||strlen($bannuser)<6)
        {
            echo "<b>Length Of Username Is Must Be Between 6 and 25 Characters Long!</b>";
        }
        else
            {
                $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO banned (bannuser,TypeBan,Reviewed,ModNote,Reason,OffenItem,BanLengthMssg,ReleaseMssg,AppealMssg) VALUES ('$bannuser','$TypeBan','$Reviewed','$ModNote','$Reason','$OffenItem','$BanLengthMssg','$ReleaseMssg','$AppealMssg')");

                die ("<b>The Moderation Report Has Been Submitted! The User Is Now Banned!</b> <b><a href='home.php'>[Home]</a></b>");
            }


 }
 else
 {
    echo 'Please enter a Username';
 }
}
```

html on botton..... Form element got caught here  while editing this post -> 
    
          Username:

```
      <div align="left">TypeBan(<i>Remember if you set a ban date make sure the TypeBan is the same as the Ban Length Message</i>):
      <select name="TypeBan">
      <option value="Reminder">Reminder</option>
      <option value="Warning">Warning</option>
      <option value="Banned for 1 Day">Banned for 1 Day</option>
      <option value="Banned for 3 Days">Banned for 3 Days</option>
      <option value="Banned for 7 Days">Banned for 7 Days</option>
      <option value="Banned for 14 Days">Banned for 14 Days</option>
      <option value="Account Deleted">Account Deleted</option>
      <option value="Account Under Admisitrative Review">Account Under Admisitrative Review</option>
      </select></div><p>


      Reviewed:
      <input type='text' readonly='readonly' name='Reviewed' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>'/><p>

      Moderator Note:
      <select name="ModNote">
      <option value="Don't create accounts just to harass users or break rules.">Don't create accounts just to harass users or break rules.</option>
      <option value="Don't say inappropriate things on PyroStudio.">Don't say inappropriate things on PyroStudio.</option>
      <option value="Don't lie about being an admin.">Don't lie about being an admin.</option>
      <option value="Don't exceed Account Spending Limit.">Don't exceed Account Spending Limit.</option>
      <option value="Don't harass/threaten/abuse/offend our employees or members.">Don't harass/threaten/abuse/offend our employees or members.</option>
      <option value="Don't provide false or inaccurate information.">Don't provide false or inaccurate information.</option>
      <option value="Don't use Services in any manner restricted by or inconsistent with the Agreement and Policies.">Don't use Services in any manner restricted by or inconsistent with the Agreement and Policies</option>
      <option value="Don't provide false, inaccurate, dated, or unveriable identification or credit information.">Don't provide false, inaccurate, dated, or unveriable identification or credit information.</option>
      </select><p>

      Reason:
      <select name="Reason">
      <option value="Inappropriate">Inappropriate</option>
      <option value="Adult Content">Adult Content</option>
      <option value="Profanity">Profanity</option>
      <option value="Harassment">Harassment</option>
      <option value="Suspicious Activity">Suspicious Activity</option>
      <option value="">N/A</option>
      </select><p>

      Offensive Item:
      <input type='text' name='OffenItem' value=''/><p>

      Ban Length Message:
      <select name="BanLengthMssg">
      <option value="This is just a Reminder">This is just a Reminder</option>
      <option value="This is just a Warning">This is just a Warning</option>
      <option value="Your account has been disabled for 1 day">Your account has been disabled for 1 day</option>
      <option value="Your account has been disabled for 3 days">Your account has been disabled for 3 days</option>
      <option value="Your account has been disabled for 7 days">Your account has been disabled for 7 days</option>
      <option value="Your account has been disabled for 14 days">Your account has been disabled for 14 days</option>
      <option value="Your Account Has Been Terminated">Your Account Has Been Terminated</option>
      <option value="Your account is Temporarily Frozen for Suspicious Activity and will be reactivated when the Administrators are done reviewing your Account.">Your account is Temporarily Frozen for Suspicious Activity and will be reactivated when the Administrators are done reviewing your Account.</option>
      </select><p>

      Release Message(You may re-activate it after Y-m-d):
      <input type='text' name='ReleaseMssg' value=''/><p>

      Appeal Mssg(Select the Blank space if account is deleted):
      <select name="AppealMssg">
      <option value="If you wish to appeal, please send an email to info.pyrostudio@gmail.com or just wait until ban date is over.">If you to appeal, please send an email to info.pyrostudio@gmail.com or just wait until ban date is over.</option>
      <option value="Your Account is under Administrative review and may or may not be reactivated depending on the infraction.">(Frozen/Suspended Account)</option>
      <option value="">No Appeal For `Account Deleted` members</option>
      </select><p>

      <input type="submit" name="post" value="Submit Report" /> | <a href="home.php">[ Home ]</a>

</form></div>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: I get no errors @Fred-ii-

Comment: There are a few possible reasons why it could be failing *silently*. If your form doesn't explicitly state that it's a POST method (forms default to GET if omitted) and your column(s) type(s) and/or lengths are not correct. This I did help someone with the same problem yesterday, due to those same factors.

Comment: I did use the POST method <form method="post" action="ModPanel.php"  >

Comment: You'll need to echo your queries and `var_dump();` to see what's going through or not. Plus, place a few echo's here and there to see what's successfully being executed `echo "query one... ok";` etc. also check your column names and you've chosen the right DB/table. That's another possibility. Another thing, if data contains spaces, which will also be a factor in silent failure.

Comment: I used the `var_dump()` function and used a few echo's. A form data is there. It's just not passing into the table. Also, the table name is correct.

Comment: It would be safer if you change to placeholders instead of string interpolation on your queries.

Comment: Then do `var_dump($_POST);` or `print_r($_POST);` at the very beginning of your script; if nothing shows, then your problem is elsewhere. Also, if you're using a button type instead of a submit type for your  submit button, that will also prevent it from working. And/or if you're using Ajax/JS that you may be using. Hard to say without seeing more/full code and I can't keep commenting back and forth like this.

Comment: try using this statement  $namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT bannuser FROM banned WHERE bannuser='$bannuser'") or die(mysql_error());
see if u get any error there

Comment: i used the `print_r($_POST)` and in there it includes my button but the type of my button is `type="submit"` here is what I get `[post] => Submit Report`

Comment: it takes the name of the button when u post values... can u give the html of your submit button

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="post" value="Submit Report" />` everything is matched up right

Comment: yes does look right for the button, check with the query by putting the die after the query as shown above... just confirm if the program goes inside the loop

Comment: Ok, well that single post from print_r tells me that your form elements do not have a name attribute. Please add your complete form to your question.

Comment: I did give my elements name attributes also, if I did add the whole form, it would take a while since it uses alot of drop down boxes and would look cluttered. And Since I know that I gave my attributes names. That's why i didnt include it in the form here.

Comment: is the program going inside the loop? try giving an echo after the if statement and check

Comment: Yeah, it does display the echo message

Comment: try db connections first by doing this :


                    mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

if the connection is set correct try this :

           $namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT bannuser FROM banned WHERE bannuser='$bannuser'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Yeah, i don't get any error.

Comment: try this too mysql_query("INSERT INTO banned (bannuser,TypeBan,Reviewed,ModNote,Reason,OffenItem,BanLengthMssg,ReleaseMssg,AppealMssg) VALUES ('$bannuser','$TypeBan','$Reviewed','$ModNote','$Reason','$OffenItem','$BanLengthMssg','$ReleaseMssg','$AppealMssg')") or die(mysql_error());  or echo the insert statement and try executing it on php... see if any error is shown... can u tell me what is seen on the screen once the process of submit is done

Answer (score 0):

Try to print something inside the else part and comment out the query execution to confirm that, it is at least going inside 'else' part

else
            {
**echo "Entering in else condition";**

// $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ...");
            }

If it is entering. Next step would be to directly execute the query through phpmyadmin or MySQL console to double check the query. Sometimes I experienced that the back quote symbol (`) in column names also plays a role

```
"INSERT INTO banned (`bannuser`,`TypeBan`,`Reviewed`,`ModNote`,`Reason`,`OffenItem`,`BanLengthMssg`,`ReleaseMssg`,`AppealMssg`) VALUES ('$bannuser','$TypeBan','$Reviewed','$ModNote','$Reason','$OffenItem','$BanLengthMssg','$ReleaseMssg','$AppealMssg')");
```

Comment: I added the `` in my sql statement and nothing happened.

Comment: If it is going upto else part, and there is nothing wrong in query then, did you confirmed that it is connecting to the database 

 $connect = mysql_connect("####","####","####");
  if (!$connect)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("####", $connect);

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the query in your browser first to see what is inside the values, copy that from browser and execute it via phpmyadmin and if you get the values in database, then execute it through php code

```
else { 
$queryreg = "INSERT INTO banned (bannuser,TypeBan,Reviewed,ModNote,Reason,OffenItem,BanLengthMssg,ReleaseMssg,AppealMssg) VALUES ('$bannuser','$TypeBan','$Reviewed','$ModNote','$Reason','$OffenItem','$BanLengthMssg','$ReleaseMssg','$AppealMssg')";

echo $queryreg; 

mysql_query($queryreg); 
}
```